# Quill.js: I've tried multiple video embeds, all have same problem: only display "no video support in your browser"

Tags: html, video, html5-video, quill

Using Quill.js as a content editor, it always chooses to display the "no video support in your browser" default text from my video tags. I've tried several of the video embed modules people have made, and they all do the same: only display the "no video support in your browser" text.

I have other pages not using Quill.js where I hand write the video tags, referencing the same videos as I want to embed with Quill.js, and those playback fine.

When attempting to embed a video within Quill.js, I see my Network tab receiving data, and I see my logs reporting the video file being located, opened... and then not streamed because Quill.js is choosing the default text and not playing the video. It does not matter if I'm attempting locally streamed video, or an IP camera I know works, or YouTube, or some other video service: behavior is always that default "not playing" text.

I even tried the htmlEditButton module that lets one just type in html, and that also only displays the "no video support" text - yet that same html can be rendered without quill.js and videos appear and playback just fine...

What's the secret? There has got to be some weakly documented aspect in play here...

Comment: If you have web space, I suggest you put a demo page there showing the problem in action. It'll be faster to diagnose a problem we can see. Share a link to the basic demo and someone might find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found by inserting the below logic from the *Quill-Examples-and-FAQ -> Centralized Video* example into my Quill implementation, multiple video embedding modules I'd been trying starting working. I think the key is the extractVideoUrl() method's allowing of an ordinary link, where the default treatment by video is to only allow YouTube and Vimeo links.

```
let DefaultVideo = Quill.import('formats/video');
//
class CentralizedVideo extends DefaultVideo {
    static create(value) {
        // Get node from superclass.
        let node = super.create(value);

        // user fields:
        let insertElemWidth  = document.getElementById("insertVideoWidth").value;
        let insertElemHeight = document.getElementById("insertVideoHeight").value;
        //
        // Set width and height.
        node.width = parseInt(insertElemWidth);
        node.height = parseInt(insertElemHeight);

        // Get url in correct format. Without it, the video will not work.
        value = this.extractVideoUrl(value);
        node.setAttribute('src', value);

        node.classList.add('ql-align-center');

        return node;
    }

    static value(node){
        return node.getAttribute('src');
    }

    static extractVideoUrl(url) {
        // look for youtube urls:
        let match =
            url.match(/^(?:(https?):\/\/)?(?:(?:www|m)\.)?youtube\.com\/watch.*v=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/,) ||
            url.match(/^(?:(https?):\/\/)?(?:(?:www|m)\.)?youtu\.be\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/);
        // if a youtube url, use their embed:
        if (match) {
            return `${match[1] || 'https'}://www.youtube.com/embed/${ match[2] }?showinfo=0`;
        }
        // if a vimeo url, use their embed:
        if ((match = url.match(/^(?:(https?):\/\/)?(?:www\.)?vimeo\.com\/(\d+)/))) {
            return `${match[1] || 'https'}://player.vimeo.com/video/${match[2]}/`;
        }
        // just let raw video url pass thru:
        return url;
    }
}
//
Quill.register(CentralizedVideo);
```